# Given 3 events (A, B and C) calculate probability of C happening and A and B not happening

Tags: probability

Ok so let me begin by giving you certain values:

$$P(A) = 0.2 \\ P(B) = 0.1 \\ P(C) = 0.05 \\ P(A \cap B) = 0.06 \\ P(A \cap C) = 0.03 \\ P(B \cap C) = 0.03 \\ P(A \cap B \cap C) = 0.02$$

I have to calculate $P(A \setminus (B \cap C))$, which is equal to $0.13$.
I tried to expand that equation and got:
$$P(A) - P(A \cap B) - P(A \cap C) - P(A \cap B \cap C)$$

Yet this does not match the answer given. Where is my mistake?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add $P(A\cap B\cap C)$ not subtract it.
Notice that when you subtract $P(A\cap B)$ and $P(A\cap C)$, then you are subtracting $P(A\cap B\cap C)$ twice.
So you need to add $P(A\cap B\cap C)$ so that you are only subtracting that value once.
This will give you $0.13$ as the result.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you very much @gd1035!